# How can I make a polymorphic component extend a Material UI React component in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, polymorphism

I’m building a component that combines a TextField (mui) and Button (mui) with some built-in styling, it can use either the built-in MUI TextField or a custom version of the MUI TextField that takes a couple of extra props. Below is a paired down version of what I have that works and builds without any issues.

```
interface ActionableTextFieldProps<P extends TextFieldProps> {
  textFieldProps: P
  textFieldComponent?: FC<any>
}

const ActionableTextField = <P extends TextFieldProps>({
  textFieldProps,
  textFieldComponent,
}: ActionableTextFieldProps<P>) => {
  const Component = textFieldComponent || TextField

  return (
      <Component
        color="primary"
        variant="outlined"
        InputProps={{
          sx: { borderRadius: '4px 0px 0px 4px', pr: 0.5 },
        }}
        {...textFieldProps}
      />
)
```

I would prefer that the Props are more dependent on the passed in textFieldComponent.

The other things I worked on my localhost but then the build failed. I start getting type errors on Component about mismatching props when I try to restrict the definition more (for example I tried textFieldComponent?: FC

). I also tried a typical polymorphic composition like below:

```
interface ActionableTextFieldProps<C extends ElementType> {
  textFieldProps: ComponentWithoutRef<C>
  textFieldComponent?: C
}

const ActionableTextField = <C extends ElementType>({
  textFieldProps,
  textFieldComponent,
}: ActionableTextFieldProps<C>) => {
  const Component = textFieldComponent || TextField

  return (
   <Stack>
      <Component
        color="primary"
        variant="outlined"
        InputProps={{
          sx: { borderRadius: '4px 0px 0px 4px', pr: 0.5 },
        }}
        {...textFieldProps}
      />
      ...
   </Stack>
)
```

The type errors are something like `Type '{ color: "primary"; variant: "outlined"; InputProps: { sx: { borderRadius: string; pr: number; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes<C>'.` When I try to further define C like using `C extends FC<any>` I get a similar error `Type '{ color: string; variant: string; InputProps: { sx: { borderRadius: string; pr: number; }; }; } & PropsWithoutRef<ComponentProps<C>>' is not assignable to type 'LibraryManagedAttributes<C, any>'`